# Mock storage when database should be injected by DI (through constructor)

Tags: php, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

I am trying to write my code as best as possible (and well testable) but here is something I am thinking about.

I have an object, where I pass dependencies through DI

```
<?php    
public function __constructor(Connection $connection) {

}
```

When I write a unit test, I take my DI Container and get the object like

```
$object = $context->getService("class");
```

And then use it`s functions.

Question is, how can I mock the connection or better, "some storage" - not neccesarilly database connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies (from my point of view) in the usage of the DIC within your test. When we do unit testing on our Symfony2 application, we mock every dependency (using [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery)). We built factories for the common mocks like a DB connection interface or a Redis connection interface, etc. This speeds up the test creation process for us.

Comment: I have been thinking about this, but I was still questioning myself, "Is it really good solution?" But when I take it from the other side, this is the only way how to cut the dependencies and test is as exact unit. Just a question, where do you do the factories? In Tests directories or in application?

Comment: We keep them with the test code as they create mocks that are only related to testing, not to the application runtime. We spare out the test directory at deployment time to keep the deliveries smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much. This does give sense.